# What is the best way to read an XML file from Embedded resources?

Tags: xml, vb.net

```vb
Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument()
Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList
Dim i As Integer
Dim str As String

xmldoc.LoadXml("countyByRegion.xml")
```

This throws

> An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally do this

```
Dim fsXML As New FileStream("countyByRegion.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

And then use `xmldoc.Load(fsXML)`

Comment: I have the xml file in embedded resource. The application that I am working on is an extension, I do not have the exact file path, I tried the code above and it gives me  "An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TriZetto\Facets\System\Config\countyByRegion.xml'."

Comment: if it is an embedded resource you should not need the full path anyway (am I missing something simple here?)

Comment: I am sorry I am really new to vb and I am using same code as you suggested and as you said for embedded resource it should not be looking for a file in other location. I am doing a research on reading a file from embedded resources right now but with very little luck till now.

Comment: This is what worked for this issue:  Dim fileText As String
        Dim a As Assembly = GetType(ClassName).Assembly
        Using reader As New StreamReader(a.GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectName.countyByRegion.xml"))
            fileText = reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using

        xmldoc.LoadXml(fileText)

Answer (score 1):

[`LoadXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx) is not used for loading files, it is for loading XML as a string. So it expects you to do something like `LoadXml("<root><bar>hi</bar></root>");` Obviously, a file name is not valid XML.

You can use [`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx) to load a file. You would use it like you are using `LoadXml` now, just specify a path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim fileText As String
    Dim a As Assembly = GetType(ZP957_Form).Assembly
    Using reader As New StreamReader(a.GetManifestResourceStream("ZP957.countyByRegion.xml"))
        fileText = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    xmldoc.LoadXml(fileText)
```

Since the xml was embedded, had to read it from the assembly for that I had to use GetManifestResourceStream and then we can do LoadXml because we now have a filestream from xml. This worked for me.